# Error Sonar NullPointerException

Tags: java, sonar

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
private List<EMQXData> getNodes() {
    List<EMQXData> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ResponseEntity<EMQX> result = emqxRestTemplate.getForEntity("/api/nodes", EMQX.class);

    try {
      if (result.getBody() != null) {
          if (!result.getStatusCode().isError()) {
          list.addAll(result.getBody().getData());
        }
      }
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
      logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      return null;
    }
    return list;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no entiendo que obtenga ese error, ya que verifico antes que result.getBody() no sea nulo.

Se trata de un error de mi código o un falso positivo de Sonar.

Comment: nunca verificas que result no sea nulo, o que getData no sea nulo. Te recomiendo intentar con Optional para evitar esa cascada de npe

Comment: Gracias por la aportación @Ruslan López, pero la verificación de tipo  if (result != null && result.getBody() != null && result.getBody().getData() != null)
      list.addAll(result.getBody().getData());    no da resultado

Comment: Eso no es lo que te recomendaron en el comentario. PD. Es más fácil si editas la pregunta todas las veces que haga falta y añades (sin borrar lo anterior) allí la info adicional de lo que probaste y qué pasa entonces ("no da resultado" es una pésima descripción)